# How to replicate this behavior on iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'd like to implement this component on iOS. As far as my research went I think this is not native. I'm referring to the "Overview | Versions | Activity" bar right below the navigation bar:

[image]

I need to use this component in my app. The only difference is that it'll have more items, not only 3, so it needs to scroll... but I'm assuming that's this one does anyway, right?

Appreciate any help :)

Thanks!

Comment: Would the voters care to explain? How is this too broad? I'm asking about a specific component...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you swipe right it will go to the next tab (Overview -> Versions)?
if that's what you're trying to do then use this library.

CarbonKit: https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit

There is CarbonKit library for Xamarin as well: https://libraries.io/nuget/CarbonKit.Xamarin
To install for xamarin: http://www.nuget.org/packages/CarbonKit.Xamarin/

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need, but I'm using xamarin.ios, as tagged. Thank you again.

Comment: Check my updated answer to see if thats what you need